# problem with cdf of tensorflow-probability's MultivariateNormalDiag()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Whenever I am trying to run cdf() for the MultivariateNormalDiag() object from the tensorflow's Distribution module, I am getting an error: `Not implemented`.

Here is the error:

```
NotImplementedError: `_is_increasing` not implemented.
```

Here is the call:

```
tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=[0,0],scale_diag=[1,1]).cdf(value=np.array([0,1]))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.